# How does wildcard work in msggrep --location

Tags: location, wildcard, gnu, gettext

I am trying to use msggrep to grep some messages from a `.po` file.

I have this command:

```
msggrep --location=src/\*.tsx myfile.po
```

This command only gives translations/messages from tsx-files directly in the folder `src/` and that's a problem.

I also want to find `src/components/myComp1.tsx` and `src/components/menu/item.tsx` etc.

How can I create a wildcard, that will match just all *.tsx files in the `src/` folder and all subfolders?

Comment: You can use `find src -name *.tsx -exec your command {} \; ` this will find file in subdirectories also. [here link to answer how to use find with exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec)

Comment: Improved spelling and formatting

Comment: Shmuel: Since all the data/text is already inside the myfile.po, I can't use the find command.

Comment: With zsh you could do that ```msggrep --location=src/**/\*.tsx myfile.po```